# How can I discriminates results of a query by which part of HAVING clause was satisfied?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query with a GROUP BY and a HAVING clause. In the HAVING clause, I have an OR. The full query may look something like this:

```
SELECT JotID
FROM uv_attributes
WHERE HOC = 1 AND JotTypeID = 5
GROUP BY JotID
HAVING (MAX(CASE WHEN city = 'London' AND language = 'English' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
    AND MAX(CASE WHEN city = 'San Francisco' AND language = 'English' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1)
    OR MAX(CASE WHEN city = 'Madrid' AND language = 'Spanish' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
```

What I want is some way to discriminate in the results of SELECT whether the first part of the HAVING clause was satisfied:

```
   (MAX(CASE WHEN city = 'London' AND language = 'English' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
AND MAX(CASE WHEN city = 'San Francisco' AND language = 'English' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1)
```

or if the part after the OR was satisfied:

```
MAX(CASE WHEN city = 'Madrid' AND language = 'Spanish' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
```

or if both were satisfied.

Is there any good way to get this type of result?

Comment: Why the use of group by and having may I ask?

Comment: @shadow I realized that my example does not well illustrate why I have this group by and having clause rather than just having it in the Where clause. I'm using a Group by/Having clause because some of my queries may be more complicated, like `(MAX(CASE WHEN city = 'London' AND language = 'English' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1 AND MAX(CASE WHEN city = 'San Francisco' AND language = 'English' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1) OR MAX(CASE WHEN city = 'Madrid' AND language = 'Spanish' THEM 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1`.

Comment: In this example, I need to aggregate the values of the other columns to see if a JotID has rows where both city and language match 'London' and 'English', respective, and where both city and language match 'San Francisco' and 'English', respectively.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you just want to move the columns to the `select` clause as well:

```
SELECT JotID,
       MAX(CASE WHEN city = 'London' AND language = 'English' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as EnglishFlag,
       MAX(CASE WHEN city = 'Madrid' AND language = 'Spanish' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as SpanishFlag
FROM uv_attributes
WHERE HOC = 1 AND JotTypeID = 5
GROUP BY JotID
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN city = 'London' AND language = 'English' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
    OR MAX(CASE WHEN city = 'Madrid' AND language = 'Spanish' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1;
```

I would be tempted to add the conditions in the `WHERE` clause.  This reduces the volume of data *before* the `join` and removes the need for the `HAVING` clause.

```
SELECT JotID,
       MAX(CASE WHEN city = 'London' AND language = 'English' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as EnglishFlag,
       MAX(CASE WHEN city = 'Madrid' AND language = 'Spanish' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as SpanishFlag
FROM uv_attributes
WHERE HOC = 1 AND JotTypeID = 5 AND
      ((city = 'London' AND language = 'English') OR
       (city = 'Madrid' AND language = 'Spanish')
      )
GROUP BY JotID;
```

Comment: This is my fault for not providing enough information. Sometimes the query can have a more complex HAVING clause like 'MAX(CASE WHEN city = \'London\' AND language = \'English\' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AND MAX(CASE WHEN city = \'San Francisco\' AND language = \'English\' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), so the aggregate is actually needed in the HAVING rather that being able to be done in the WHERE clause. With this in mind, is it still possible to use your method of checking the cases in the SELECT clause? I've been trying to formulate it, but I'm not coming up with something sql server accepts.

Comment: @Imbajoe . . . Yes, you can just copy each expression in the `having` to the `select` to see if there is a match.  However, if the clauses are connected by `and` then you know there is a match, so the additional information is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Add a CASE to your SELECT list:

```
SELECT JotID,
CASE 
 WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN city = 'London' AND language = 'English' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
   AND MAX(CASE WHEN city = 'Madrid' AND language = 'Spanish' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1 THEN 'Both'
 WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN city = 'London' AND language = 'English' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1 THEN 'London'
 WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN city = 'Madrid' AND language = 'Spanish' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1 THEN 'Madrid'
 ELSE 'Neither'
END AS LondonMadrid
FROM uv_attributes
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select isNull(uv1.JotID, uv1.JotID) 
     , uv1.count as 'London and English count'
     , uv2.count as 'Madrid AND Spanish count'
from 
(
SELECT JotID, count(*) as count 
FROM uv_attributes
WHERE HOC = 1 AND JotTypeID = 5
AND city = 'London' AND language = 'English'
GROUP BY JotID
) as uv1
full outer join 
(
SELECT JotID, count(*) as count 
FROM uv_attributes
WHERE HOC = 1 AND JotTypeID = 5
AND city = 'Madrid' AND language = 'Spanish' 
GROUP BY JotID
) as UV2 
on uv1.JotID = uv2.JotID
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I 'm missing something but I think that this simple query will do the work:

```
Select 
    JotID, city+language as 'PlaceLanguage'
From 
    uv_attributes
Where 
    ( HOC = 1  )
    And ( JotTypeID = 5 )
    And (
        ( ( city = 'London' ) And ( language = 'English' ) )
        Or ( ( city = 'Madrid' ) And ( language = 'Spanish' ) )
        Or ( ( city = 'New York' ) And ( language = 'English' ) )             
        Or ( ( city = 'Barcelona' ) And ( language = 'Spanish' ) )
    )
```

I can't find use for group by and having in the original posted query. Also, in order to discriminate the results you need a second column.

But as commissioner Gordon says in Batman "...I've been wrong before" ;-)

Edited after user clarification.

After your answer to my comment I still believe that this might work as you want. Of course in case of long Ors it is better for performance to use `UNION` for each case